# point reader monad scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

is there a way, how to easily `point` a value in `Reader` context?
I can use `Reader` object and ignore the context:

```
Reader {
  _ ⇒ 3
}
```

Scalaz seems to have a method `point` for this specifically. I see, that is defined on `Applicative`. I suppose, that there is some trick, how to put a value into the `Reader` context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is in fact an `Applicative` instance for `Reader`, which you can use like this (you should of course replace `String` with whatever type you want your environment to be):

```
3.point[({type L[X] = Reader[String, X]})#L]
```

If you'd prefer to avoid the ugly type lambda and don't mind defining an extra type alias, you can write the following instead:

```
type MyReader[X] = Reader[String, X]

3.point[MyReader]
```

Scalaz 7 also provides a nice bit of shorthand that makes this even cleaner:

```
3.liftReader[String]
```

These are all more or less equivalent to each other (and to your solution), though.